# Cannot login after lock

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, ldap

When trying to login again after locking my computer, I sometimes can no longer login using the graphical interface. My username does show up, but I the bar where you'd usually fill in your password is completely grayed out. I can login to a TTY just fine.

Might this have any possible relation to me using LDAP?

Comment: sounds like a bug